# Homogeneous function differential degree

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be a homogeneous function of degree $p$. $f(tx)=t^pf(x)$ for $p>0$.

Let us assume that $f$ is continuously differentiable.
How to show that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ is a homogeneous function of degree $p-1$?

I tried to use euler's theorem $(\nabla f(x),x)=kf(x)$ but didn't manage to prove it.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Just differentiate both sides of $f(tx)=t^p f(x)$ w.r.t. $x$...

Comment: @sranthrop could you please help me with that? thanks!

Comment: I give you an example for the case $n=1$: Differentiation of both sides simply gives $f'(tx)t=t^p f'(x)$...

Comment: @sranthrop is this a differentiation with respect to $x_1$? how does this show that the degree is $p-1$?

Comment: No. As I said, this is the case $n=1$, so you have a function of only one variable. For the multi-dimensional case, replace the derivative $f'$ by its multi-dimensional equivalent, the gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\Big[f(tx)\Big]=f_i(tx)\cdot t$$

and

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\Big[t^pf(x)\Big]=t^pf_i(x)$$

Can you conclude?

Comment: thanks - yes, dividing by $p$ after comparing both derivative yields the result, I just need clarification for the chain rule: does $f_i(x)$ mean $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$?

Comment: Yes, exactly! ${}$ Also, I suppose you mean 'dividing by $t$'.

Comment: haha yes... Was much simpler than I thought... I guess I don't have enough confidence in diefferentials of multivariable functions. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help.